# Why my Spring Web app project doesn't run correctly with Web and Thymeleaf dependency?

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I've created a new Spring web project using Web and Thymeleaf dependencies,
with Maven and Spring Boot version 2.0.1 
But if I try to run it, it doesn't start on localhost port, and shut down itself with the following log messages:

```
    2018-04-17 22:44:30.089  INFO 8904 --- [           main] c.s.s.SpringJokesAppApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-04-17 22:44:31.055  INFO 8904 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3c72f59f: startup date [Tue Apr 17 22:44:30 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-17 22:44:35.418  WARN 8904 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2018-04-17 22:44:35.602  INFO 8904 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-04-17 22:44:35.638  INFO 8904 --- [           main] c.s.s.SpringJokesAppApplication          : Started SpringJokesAppApplication in 10.542 seconds (JVM running for 22.976)
2018-04-17 22:44:35.646  INFO 8904 --- [      Thread-25] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3c72f59f: startup date [Tue Apr 17 22:44:30 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-17 22:44:35.650  INFO 8904 --- [      Thread-25] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It worked when I created another project with Spring Boot version 2.0.0 ,but since then it was upgraded to 2.0.1 it doesn't runs at localhost. I think there is something problem with Tomcat, but I don't know why.

Comment: can you post your configuration file and pom.xml

Comment: My pom.xml:  https://pastebin.com/Tca5b8Yv  Configuration file is application.properties ? (sry I'm new at Spring)

Answer (score 0):

the project works fine, try to delete org.springframwork.boot from .m2 folder

Comment: Did it, but got the same error. Maybe deleting whole .m2 folder could help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with deleting the whole .m2\repository folder, then reimport all maven projects. (Maven - update) Thanks for the help!